# How to make python config file, in which relative paths are defined, but when scripts in other directories import config, paths are correct?

Tags: python, module, relative-path

I have the following directory structure for a program I'm writing in python:

```
\code\
    main.py
    config.py
    \module_folder1\
        script1.1.py
\data\
    data_file1
    data_file2
```

My `config.py` is a set of global variables that are set by the user, or generally fixed all the time. In particular `config.py` defines path variables to the 2 data files, something like `path1 = os.path.abspath("../data/data_file1")`. The primary use is to run `main.py` which imports `config` (and the other modules I wrote) and all is good.

But sometimes I need to run `script1.1.py` by itself. Ok, no problem. I can add to  `script1.1` the usual `if __name__ == '__main__':` and I can import `config`. But then I get `path1 = "../code/data/data_file1"` which doesn't exist. I thought that since the path is created in `config.py` the path would be relative to where `config.py` lives, but it's not.

So the question is, how can I have a central config file which defines relative paths, so I can import the config file to scripts in different directories and have the paths still be correct?

I should mention that the code repo will be shared among multiple machines, so hardcoding an absolute path is not an option.

Comment: There was  a comment I replied to, but now it seems to be gone. The suggestion was to use the `os.path.dirname(__file__)` in the config file ( i think) is that correct? That sounds like the kind of solution I was expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You know the correct relative path to the file from the directory where `config.py` is located
2. You know the correct relative path to the directory where `config.py` is located (in your case, `..`)

Both of this things are system-independent and do not change unless you change the structure of you project. Just add them together using `os.path.join('..', config.path_repative_to_config)`

Comment: This will work. good idea. Seems like there should be a better `os.getcwd()` function-- one that is import-to-different-directories agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

(Not sure who posted this as a comment, then deleted it, but it seems to work so I'm posting as an answer.) The trick is to use `os.path.dirname(__file__)` in the config file, which gives the directory of the config file (`/code/`) regardless of where the script that imports config is.

Specifically to answer the question, in the config file define

```
path1 = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.join( os.path.dirname(__file__) , '..'), 'data' ), 'data_file1' ) )
```